# Office Dialog API - Office.context.ui.messageParent only works on microsoft edge? (Not in Chrome/Firefox)

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

There is no any error message in the console. 
There is a **parentMessage** function available so, i tried to execute the code through console but it returns undefined and nothing happens in **Chrome/Firefox** but in **Microsoft edge** the message is execute and passed to the add-in.
It's just that the message is not being passed from **dialogBox** to our add-in.

Any solution?

P.S. It works with **displayInIframe**.

Comment: Can you please share the manifest file or any code snippet? I am not able to repro.

Comment: Check the AppDomain entries in your manifest, there should be one with your app domain, and ensure that each line has the protocol (eg https) and the domain stated, not just the domain name part.

Comment: Yes. The problem was in in <AppDomain>mywebsite.jp</AppDomain>.
      
The most interseting part is that, in Microsoft edge the code worked fine even without adding https in that url but, was not working in chrome/firefox. And I thought it was cross browser bug. So, lost my 2-3 days finding that simple one line bug.

Comment: Can we close this issue from our end, since you already found the solution?

Comment: Ok. You can close it.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I've just started noticing the same issue with Firefox and Chrome. There has been no change to the manifest for months but the problem has appeared in the last few weeks.